# Pushwoosh IOS phonegapp code integration

Tags: ios, phonegap-plugins

Hello I am currently working on my ios pushwoosh phonegapp app . I am following this [guide](http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/push-notification-sdk-integration-for-phonegap/):

i  have no idea where i need to implement this code:

```
In your onDeviceReady function add:
initPushwoosh();

bind: function() {
document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.deviceready, false);
},
deviceready: function() {
// note that this is an event handler so the scope is that of the event
// so we need to call app.report(), and not this.report()
initPushwoosh();

app.report('deviceready');
},
```

and also this code dos i need to be placed in the same file ?
Receiving push notifications. See the following snippet of code in initPushwoosh function

```
document.addEventListener('push-notification', function(event) {
var notification = event.notification;
navigator.notification.alert(notification.aps.alert);
pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this working example of phonegap integration:
https://github.com/shaders/push-notifications-sdk/tree/master/SDK%20Sample%20Projects/iPhone-Phonegap

and this javascript file, it shows where you should implement the provided code:
https://github.com/shaders/push-notifications-sdk/blob/master/SDK%20Sample%20Projects/iPhone-Phonegap/www/js/index.js